# Safari/Chrome bxSlider infinite loop issue/bug

Tags: bxslider

I'm using a bxslider to create a gallery of beers at this url: crystalspringsbrewing.com/ourbeers.php

You click on the logo for the beer and a description is provided beneath the slider. I'm doing that with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.beer-text:nth-of-type(1)').show();

  $('.beer-type').click(function(event) {
    var beerName = $(this).data('beer');
    $('.beer-text').hide();
    $('#' + beerName).show();
  });
});
```

I have set an infinite loop in the bxslider. The problem is this: If you press back once from the beginning and click on the last beer in the slider (Wuerzburger) the description is provided, but then the other slides (13, Summertime Ale, Butch) will not display their descriptions when you click on them. Nothing happens. This error occurs about 50% of the time in Chrome and Safari. Often enough to be annoying. Works fine on Firefox, so I imagine it's a bug in the browser or the bxslider. Any ideas? Try refreshing a few times if the bug doesn't occur the first time the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what's going on is that when you're getting to the end of the list, the jQuery plugin you're using is adding elements to the page dynamically. When you use $('.beer-type').click() you are setting a handler for clicks on 'beer-type' elements, but when you add a new .beer-type element, the handler has not yet been added.

The way around this is to use the jQuery function .on() which you can read about here. Back in the day, the way around this problem was to use the jQuery function .live() but now that function has been deprecated (not to be confused with depreciated) which means that it's now been phased out. The .on() function works a bit differently (especially if you're trying to effect elements that are added on the fly which you are). Here's how you can change your code to make things work again. Replace this block:

```
$('.beer-type').click(function(event) {
    var beerName = $(this).data('beer');
    $('.beer-text').hide();
    $('#' + beerName).show();
});
```

With this block:

```
$(document).on('click', '.beer-type', function() {
    var beerName = $(this).data('beer');
    $('.beer-text').hide();
    $('#' + beerName).show();
});
```

Hope that helps!